# NetSuite: How to give access to Custom Role to only view certain "Views" in NetSuite

Tags: netsuite

Please help, this seems simple and I think it is possible in NetSuite but I was unable to find any option.

In Administrator Role, from the list view of a custom record I was able to create a new View with specific criteria using "Customize View" button. Now when I change to a Custom Role and navigate to custom record's list, on top I am able to see both options in VIEW field: "Default" and "My Custom View".
How can I restrict my Custom Role to only access/view "My Custom View" and not "Default" view?

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Custom views are created via saved searches (even though it doesn't look like it when using the "Custom View" button).  To find the search you can use the global search bar to search for "sea: Custom View".  Edit the corresponding search.  To allow/disallow user access to each view/search, update the "Audience" tab.  To make this custom view the default for specific roles, use the "Roles" tab.  Reference Suite answer id [8492](https://netsuite.custhelp.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/8492/kw/8492)